# Reading bluetooth low energy data from a custom app to a ble dongle(csr8510)

Tags: python, linux, android-studio, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am having a problem connecting and sending Bluetooth low energy data from a custom built app I created in android studio to a BLE dongle. The app I created has 4 virtual push buttons and every time I press one these buttons its send a 4bit number letting the Bluetooth dongle( peripheral) know. The problem is that when I use "hcidump" in Linux I cant read anything. which I figured is how I can view this data.

One of the problems I believe I am having is that I need to advertise some command that lets the app know what information I want. If this is the case I'm unsure what to send, to notify the app that I want to read the states of the virtual pushbuttons.

I am able to bring up the ble dongle in Linux and the app is able to discovery the ble dongle as well they will connect for a short period then disconnect cause as I said the app is waiting for some kind of characteristic/service or so is what I believe?

Comment: Did you write your apps on Linux? I understand that you just created your app on your mobile phone. You should define your service/characteristic(here can be your four virtual button) above csr8510 and your mobile phone app need search the service then write the characteristic, i.e. the four button value, push down or up.

Answer (score 0):

I am also looking forward for something similar application where Android application sends some button command to Linux Application via Bluetooth and nearest similar example I get from github.

Here is [Python application](https://gist.github.com/dvas0004/8209b67ff556cb18651d#file-aquapi-py) code for Linux side this is using Bluetooth RFCOMM communication.

And here is [Android application](https://gist.github.com/dvas0004/3b9128d94c0ecd50588a#file-aquariumdroid-java) main activity code you have to make sure to put your Bluetooth name in android application and also make sure UUID is same on both python and android application.

Give it a try and then you can modify both your application for multiple buttons.

Make sure you have paired your bluetooth with android first before you run application.